# Use Multiple keywords with mysql Like

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-like

I want to write mysql query to display all records if text field value = "All" or else display records similar to keyword value. I have written code below to just to give an idea.

```
if (keyword = 'All' )
    select * from ItemMain
else if (keyword like %itemname%)
    select * from ItemMain
```

Comment: couldn't you just OR the two clauses?

Comment: i dont know how to use if else inside mysql query.

Comment: Since your two 'then' clauses are identical you don't need the else if.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but the details are a bit confusing. The name of the table is `ItemMain`, but what is the name of the column with the "text field value"? And where does `keyword` come from?

Comment: Better to control that from the script which generated the query. You can do with query, but it wont utilize the index well like select * from table where '$var' = 'ALL' OR keyword like '%xx%'

Comment: @graceemile  keyword comes from GUI combo box. if user has selected 'ALL Items' from combobox, GUI table should display all items, else if user typed part of item name on combobox(its editable), GUI table should display all items contains that keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If itemname is your column name, and your search string parameter replaces the `?` in your code.  Then your statement should look something like this if you are searching for all itemnames containing your search string:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     ItemMain
WHERE    ? = 'All' OR itemname LIKE '%?%'
```

Or this if you are looking for an exact match:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     ItemMain
WHERE    ? = 'All' OR itemname = ?
```

Comment: So far it worked for me only for keyword All. There is syntax error on my sql query. I use preparedStatement on java. Here ? gets textfiled values. String sql ="SELECT * FROM ItemMain WHERE ? = 'All' OR ? like %itemName%";  %itemName% is table column.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming PHP as the front-end language you can put it all in one query like this (forgive the curly braces; I'm never sure when they're needed or not so I tend to over-use them):

```
$query = <<< ENDSQL
SELECT *
  FROM ItemMain
  WHERE ('{$keyword}' = 'All') OR (your_textfield like '%{$keyword}%')
ENDSQL;
... execute the query
```

But really I'd go with the suggestion from @cjg and use two different queries:

```
$query = "";
if ($keyword == 'All') {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM ItemMain";
} else {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM ItemMain WHERE your_textfield LIKE '%{$keyword}%'";
}
... execute the query
```